# simple shopping basket written in ASP

Tags: asp-classic, shopping-cart

What i need a `simple shopping basket written in ASP`.

I have looked around and there are some great full-blown `ecommerce` solutions out there, but they are beyond my needs and abilities.

What I am looking for is an ASP based Shopping cart, in which

```
No database required
Simple shopping experience for up to a dozen products
Object Oriented design 
CSS style semantically correct
Easy integration with 3rd party payment processor
Supports downloadable soft goods
```

I want to use my own (payment method) **checkout button**
They provide functionality to add items into a shopping cart, capture user information and forward to a **3rd party payment processor.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say for you to check on www.hotscripts.com

What do you want, if not static pages/content,  would have to use a database.

About easy integration with third party payments system you should be able to get that information from the third party itself.

you would be better off with a full system anyway (i think).

check hot scripts for waht you are looking for, I am sure you can find something there

cheers

PC